# Profile network java (jdbc)

Tags: java, jdbc, time

Qual  a ferramenta que posso usar para avaliar o tempo de resposta de uma requisição (jdbc)

Ex:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE '%Oracle%'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
// linha de cima ⋀ 
// quanto tempo demorou nesse meio ?
// linha de baixo ⋁
rs.next();
```

No log aparece

```
15:58:35.175 INFO - 6. SELECT * FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE '%Oracle%'; {executed in 1 ms}
```

De fato a query foi executada com `1ms` mas existe um `gap` entre executar a query e carregar essa informação.

**Qual ferramenta posso usar para obter tal informação?**

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas ferramentas comerciais que podem fazer isso, mas nunca as usei.

Basicamente você deve medir, de alguma forma, o tempo decorrido na chamada do método `executeQuery` e métodos correlatos.

O que geralmente é feito nas empresas onde trabalhei é instrumentalizar as instâncias de `Connection`, `Statement` e correlatas para medir os tempos. Infelizmente cada uma tem uma solução.

Aqui na Atlassian temos um plugin para o JIRA que, quando carregado, é capaz de modificar as classes em tempo de execução e assim coletar as informações de *profiling*.

Isso é feito usando um *java agent*, que possibilita adicionar instrumentação às classes. [Veja a documentação do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) para maiores detalhes.

Há um tutorial sobre como fazer um mini profiler usando instrumentação [aqui](http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html).

A alternativa mais simples é simplesmente injetar sua verão do `Connection` e classes correlatas nas demais classes do seu sistema, como já mencionei acima.

Comment: No  meu caso o banco fica na nuvem e a aplicação em outro nó, o que eu preciso e do tempo que aplicação e banco de dados leva para se comunicar (requisição/resposta). Com essa informação a sua resposta muda ou continua a mesma? Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @BrunoRozendo Se você quer o tempo total, isto é, incluindo o tempo decorrido para o Java enviar a query para o banco, a execução da query e ainda o tempo para a resposta do banco até o Java, a solução é essa mesma. Por outro lado, se quiser cada valor individual aí a solução tem que ser num nível mais baixo, por exemplo, monitorando a rede.

Comment: Muito obrigado.